# perl not able to delete a file using Unlink

Tags: perl

I am using a perl script that takes directory name as input from user and searches files in it. After searching file it reads the contents of file. If file contents contain a word "cricket" then using unlink function I should be able to delete the file. But using `unlink` the file that contains the word "cricket" still exists in the directory after execution of the code. Please help.  My code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

print "enter a directory name\n";
my $dir = <>;
print "you have entered $dir \n";
chomp($dir);
opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open directory $!";

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
    my $filepath = "${dir}${file}";
    print "$filepath\n";
    print " $file \n";

    open(my $fh, '<', $filepath) or die "unable to open the $file  $!";
    my $count = 0;
    while (my $row = <$fh>) {
        chomp $row;
        if ($row =~ /cricket/) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    print "$count";

    if ($count == 0) {
        chomp($filepath);
        unlink $filepath;
        print " $filepath deleted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the permission to write to that file?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to `unlink` an open file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your test `if($count==0) {...}` you'll only delete files if they **don't** contain "cricket". It should work as you describe if you change it to `if($count) {...}`.

Additionally you're creating the filepath by concatenating the dir and file names in a manner that will *only work if the dir name the user entered includes a trailing slash* (`${dir}${file}`): this would be less error-prone as `$dir/$file`, or, if you wanted to go to town:

```
use File::Spec;
File::Spec::catfile($dir, $file);
```

Additionally, as the comments point out, you're not closing the open file handle, whether or not you try to delete it. This is bad practice, however, on Linux at least it should still work. Use `close($fh)` before your deletion test.

Note also that "cricket" is case-sensitive so files with "Cricket" won't be deleted. Use `$row =~ /cricket/i` for case-insensitive search.

Comment: ok thank you..if i change that also ie if($count) still its not working

Comment: is there any way i can concatinate dir name and file name by placing /(slash) between them?

Comment: @user2775241: that's what `File::Spec::catfile` should do, in an OS-independent way.